# dplyr syntax to replace all elements of a vector after a certain value

Tags: r, dplyr

What could be the dplyr syntax for replacing all elements (by `0`) after a certain condition (`x < 0`) is first reach

```
x <- c(1, 2, 4, -1, 1, 3)
if(any(x < 0)) x[min(which(x < 0)):length(x)] <- 0
> x
[1] 1 2 4 5 0 0 0
```

Comment: Not `dplyr` but working: `replace(x, cumsum(x < 0) >= 1, 0)`

Comment: since `tibble(x =  c(1, 2, 4, -1, 1, 3)) %>%
        mutate(x = replace(x, cumsum(x == -1) >= 1, 0))` works, I guess it's a tidyverse compliant answer.

Comment: Or `x * !cumsum(x < 0)`

Comment: really useful. this answer my question. Is there such thing as "tidyverse compliant"?

Comment: Not really, I don't think. As long as the expression works in a `mutate()` call I guess you could say it's a good fit with tidyverse, some things like `rowSums` don't work there.